# Алгорифм Маркова

Tags: алгоритм, c++

Подскажите, пожалуйста, встречали ли вы шаблоны к алгорифмам Маркова? Если да, то дайте ссылку на источник.

Comment: ребят, неужели ни у кого  нет таких шаблонов??